# How to make the list scroll inside the parent without setting the static height in Extjs 6.x?

Tags: extjs, extjs6-modern, extjs6.2

Is it possible to scroll the list without setting some static height,
I need to make the list to scroll independent of its parent controls.

```
    {
    xtype: 'panel',
    layout: {
        type: 'fit',
        align: 'stretch'
    },
    items: [{
        xtype: 'list',
        //height:'350px', //working for static height
        scrollable: true,
        itemTpl: '{title}',
        data: [{
            title: 'Item 1'
        }]
      }]
   }
```

[Here is the Sencha Fiddle link](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/243a)

Comment: Under what condition do you want scroll to appear? If parent component allows list to be displayed without a scroll, it will. If height of parent component is less than height of the list, scroll will appear. This is correct behavior.

Comment: The panel that contains the list doesn't have any height assigned to it, so it's naturally heighted.

Comment: in my fiddle example un-comment the //height:'350px', the list will get proper scrolling behaviour. I want similar behaviour without setting the height, is any way that the parent panel will stop extending the list out of its body ? So that list will have the height of parent panel then the list will get the scroll for its item which is not in viewing area.